# Insert Date to MySql using c#

Tags: c#, mysql

I have Date field in my mysql table. I want to insert the date through my Date picker control
of windows forms c#. How ?

when i tried using below, i am getting error.

Code :

```
DB.Insert_Orders(Convert.ToInt32(txtA.Text), Convert.ToInt32(txtB.Text), Convert.ToInt32(txtC.Text), DTP_date.Value.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd"));


Error :
{MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException: Incorrect datetime value: '15' for column 'Date' at row
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try

```
DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
```

Or

```
DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMddHHmmss");
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to convert the value of datetime picker in to type DateTime. Then pass the value.