# How to insert DateTime in MySql Database using C# code

Tags: c#, mysql

```
2/1/2009 5:04:15 AM
```

I get it from MySQL database and want to feed it in table from other where i get it.

But it not worked in C# but using gui it work.

How i can feed this date to MySQL database using C# code.

Comment: How to get a date from MySql database to C# DateTime object?: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/573153/how-to-get-a-date-from-mysql-database-to-c-datetime-object

Comment: What is your code to add the date? And what exception do you get?

Comment: Duplicate question. Solution was posted here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3279866/insert-date-to-mysql-using-c-sharp

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
    string dt;   
    string dt2;
    DateTime date = DateTime.Now;    
    DateTime date2 = DateTime.Now;    
    dt = date.ToLongTimeString();        // display format:  11:45:44 AM
    dt2 = date2.ToShortDateString();     // display format:  5/22/2010

    cmd.Parameters.Add("@time_out", SqlDbType.NVarChar,50).Value = dt;
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@date_out", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 50).Value = dt2;
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@date_time", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 50).Value = string.Concat(dt2, " ", dt); // display format:  11/11/2010 4:58:42
```

Answer (score 7):

If you work with the `MySqlCommand` class, you should be able to use a `DateTime` with the following construct:

```
using (var command = connection.CreateCommand())
{
    command.CommandText = "INSERT INTO table (dateTimeColumn) VALUES (@1)";

    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@1", DateTime.Now);

    command.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

This should ensure that the date/time is stored correctly.

Answer (score 4):

Simply Do following Code

```
string dt;   
string dt2;
DateTime date = DateTime.Now;    
DateTime date2 = DateTime.Now;    
dt = date.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd H:mm:ss");  
dt2 = date2.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd H:mm:ss");
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if I know exactly where you are having this problem, but if it's after reading the information from the Database to your C# application you may want to take a look at CultureInfo.

```
CultureInfo MyCultureInfo = new CultureInfo("en-US");

DateTime date = DateTime.Parse(strDate, MyCultureInfo, DateTimeStyles.NoCurrentDateDefault);
```

This should allow you to convert '2/1/2009 5:04:15 AM' to a DateTime format.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo(VS.71).aspx

Answer (score 0):

This will work:

```
string today_date;   
DateTime date = DateTime.Now;
today_date=date.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
```

Answer (score -2):

Just download the sample program here for much easier tutorial. http://jhamnariz.weebly.com/3/archives/05-2012/1.html . Hope it helps.